# Database file is not copying from assets to data/data/<package name>/databases

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, assets

There are so many questions related to this problems but none of them helped to me. If I see the logic of my code it should work but still not working at all. I did this in my previous project at that time it was working fine but not now.

When the application is installed the database file is in /data/data//databases/ path. But says error that: (1) no such table:table name. Then I opened the database file using SQLite Browser and I can see that there is only one table android_metadata. Other tables are missing. It clears explains that the database has not been copying from assets folder. Instead, it is creating new database in the given path. If the given path is in the SDCard then, I do not have SD card on my phone and my phone is rooted. I need to change the permission of data/data//databases/ directories each time when the application is installed for the first time to see the data of databases.

But my application does not crash when I pull dynamically the database file from assets folder to /data/data//databases/. For sure, I do not want this to do. Please could you look at my code and figure out what could be changed. Thanks!!

```
public DatabaseHelper() throws IOException {
    super(Attendance.getContext(), DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    /*try {
        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    boolean dbexist = checkDataBase();
    if(dbexist){
        openDataBase();
    }else{
        createDataBase();
    }
}

/**
 * Database maintains global state in application
 * 
 * @return singleton instance
 */
public static DatabaseHelper getInstance() {

    if (mInstance == null) {
        try {
            mInstance = new DatabaseHelper();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return mInstance;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbexist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbexist) {

    }else{
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try{
            copyDataBase();
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    // SQLiteDatabase checkDataBase = null;
    boolean checkDataBase =true;
    try {
        String Path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbFile = new File(Path);
        /*
         * checkDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Path, null,
         * SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
         */
        checkDataBase = dbFile.exists();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("CheckDb", "DB not found");
        // database does't exist yet.
    }
    return checkDataBase;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from local assets-folder to the just created empty
 * database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local database as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Open the empty db as the output stream.
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the stream.
    myOutput.close();
    myOutput.flush();
    myInput.close();
    Log.i("Database", "New database has been copied to device!");

}

/**
 * Open the database
 * 
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Log.i("DB....", "database opened....");
    return db != null;
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if (mInstance != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();
}
```

Logcat:

```
02-27 13:30:26.509: D/AndroidRuntime(20480): Shutting down VM
02-27 13:30:26.509: W/dalvikvm(20480): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x4188eba8)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480): Process: <package-name>, PID: 20480
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<package-name>/<package-name>.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at com.Areva.areva_attendance.helper.DatabaseHelper.copyDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:172)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at com.Areva.areva_attendance.helper.DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:130)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at com.Areva.areva_attendance.helper.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:94)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at com.Areva.areva_attendance.helper.DatabaseHelper.getInstance(DatabaseHelper.java:107)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at com.Areva.areva_attendance.model.Portfolio.<init>(Portfolio.java:25)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at com .Areva.areva_attendance.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-27 13:30:26.509: E/AndroidRuntime(20480):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I posted up :)

Comment: Is the log from the first time you open the app? (after clearing data or uninstall/reinstall)

Comment: @Murphy I did all but it is not working that way also . But I figure out where my code is not working. Could you check my context.getAssets().open(); From that line it is crashing.

Comment: Are you using debug mode to trace your code errors? What error are you getting? NullPointerException? Where do you get your context from? It's better to pass it as an function argument.

Comment: @Murphy Dude I am doubting the context of the Database Helper class. I am trying to make the Database Helper class a global state application that extends Application. I am again posting my logcat error. This happens when database is being trying to copy from assets.

Comment: Likely `context` is null but the question doesn't show how you declare or initialize it.

Comment: @laalto I have this befire constructor;
private static Context context;

Comment: That's the declaration, do you initialize it i.e. assign a value to it?

Comment: @laalto I think no!! What I am trying to do is making this databasehelper class as a global state(Singleton) that extends Application. If you are asking this. in public DatabaseHelper() constructore i have super(Attendance.getContext()). I was thinking that is working as a context.

Comment: Can you try Attendance.getContext().getApplicationContext() instead? (is never null when the application is running)

Comment: @Murphy Still not working :( . I have same error like thos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589275/getting-error-in-sqlite-database-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriously!! I don't believe this. I just added **db.openDataBase();** function on the first query of my app, then it worked. I cannot believe this. What I realize now is that I should open database before I query. It might help other in this kind of problem. CHEERSS!! :D

And do not forget to db.close in pause() and on resume() db.open();

Comment: I thought it was crashing when copying the db with context.getAssets().open();?

Comment: @Murphy No buddy. It is not crashing. I did not have any errors on my code. I just forgot to open database for the query after creating and copying into the database folder. That was my stupid mistake. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your DB_PATH is hardcoded.

You should use `Environment.getDataDirectory()` to get the internal storage path, as Android could locate it at a different place depending on the device/OS version.